# MongoDB $gt/$lt operators with datatype of Array and key value pair as strings. How to compare negative value of string type from array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I'm trying to execute a query on MongoDB Compass and Robo 3T for value greater than/less than a user specified number. In my database, value are stored like :

```
 "Attributes":
     [{
        "Key": "Score",
        "Value": "-25"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Country",
        "Value": "India"
    }]
```

I tried with below queries but I am not getting result. Negative symbol is not being considered for comparison.

User Specified Number: -27

Robo 3T:

```
1. db.getCollection('Resource').find({ Attributes: { $elemMatch: { Key:"Score" ,Value: { "$gt" : "-27" }} } })
2. db.getCollection('Resource').find({ Attributes: { $elemMatch: { Key:"Score" ,Value: { "$gt" : -27 }} } })
```

MongoDB Compass:

```
{ "Attributes": { $elemMatch: { Key: { $eq: "Score" } ,Value: { $gt:"-27"}  } } }
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Try $expr with $convert. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/